Mesh deforming after parenting with automatic weights
I am having a problem with parenting with automatic weights. I have followed a lot of the guidance listed in other posts.
I have cleared all parenting, applied transforms then re-parented all bones but every time I parent with automatic weights the mesh always deforms. I have removed all of the IK and Pole bones from deforming the mesh. I am still relatively inexperienced regarding rigging, I have attached the project file. Could someone just explain what is the right procedure to follow in the future, I am still learning the workflow but no one has mentioned this in any tutorials.
Thanks


Project file: https://mega.nz/file/DJtn3RSI#xsj0bneEScKxIH6bCBFmQvlblXKY-Qog7JzSP56zrhs
I can just send screenshots of my current settings if you do not want to download the file. I apologise if it appears that I am not learning for myself, I have tried to find a solution in various tutorials for a few hours so I just want to know from some professionals. If someone can just explain their workflow or a solution it would be great.

Set the armature into Pose mode, 'a' (select all), then Pose::"Apply Post as Rest".  Then re-parent with Auto_weights.

You need to bend the elbow a bit backwards in Edit mode so that Blender knows how it is supposd to bend in Pose mode:

Also, giving a pole target may twist the arm, correct the Pole Angle in Pose mode so that the arm is correctly rotated:


Thank you very much for that answer that was the exact solution. Thank you for taking the time to tell me what was wrong. Just for future reference, how would I find the perfect pole angle, since my mesh doesnt allow for the regular 180 or 90 degrees, the only way I was able to get the correct angle was by looking at how the arm texture aligned with the rest of the model. Thanks, Max
